# Objects change their places?

Tags: animation

I don't know where is my mistake ? every time when make I animation of objects and then change the frame rate, all objects moves to the selected one ?!! I don't want them to change their places like that. How to solve this ?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you upload your.blend file to be able to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number highlighted below indicates that your objects share one action which means that they all share the same keyframes.

[image: action with multiple users]

You can create an copy of the action for the active object by clicking on the number. After that you should be able to modify the object's keyframes individually.

**Update:**
If you want to affect multiple objects by a single action, I think the default approach would be to add an armature with a bone for every object, add a Child-Of constraint to each object, choosing the specific bone, and then creating an action which animates the bones.

[image: armature with bone for each object]

[image: child-of constraint]

Comment: But like this I will have 3 animations for every object rather than 3 animations for all objects. Example, "first action", all objects moves around. In the "second action", all objects go up  and down. How to do this ?

Comment: @user43474 I expanded the answer to include a method of grouping related animations for different objects together in one action.